# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dolphin' when running pytest

Tags: python

now I am using pytest to run Python 3 unit test, this is my code:

```
from dolphin.biz.notifier.dingtalk.dingtalk_impl import DingtalkImpl


class TestDingtalk:

    def test_send_message(self):
        dingtalkImpl = DingtalkImpl()
        dingtalkImpl.send_dingtalk_notify_message(1)
```

then I run this command to execute unit test in path `/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/test/cert/dingtalk`:

```
pytest test_dingtalk.py
```

but shows this error(only happen in unit test):

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/test/cert/dingtalk/test_dingtalk.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/home/dolphin/anaconda3/envs/pydolphin/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_dingtalk.py:1: in <module>
    from dolphin.biz.notifier.dingtalk.dingtalk_impl import DingtalkImpl
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dolphin'
=========================================================================================== short test summary info ============================================================================================
ERROR test_dingtalk.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================================================================================== 1 error in 0.05s ===============================================================================================
```

my proejct structure like this:

[image]

I have tried to specify the python path like this:

`set PYTHONPATH=/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin && pytest test_dingtalk.py`

still did not work, what should I do to make it work?I also tried this way:

```
 pytest ./test/cert/dingtalk/test_dingtalk.py
```

Comment: if your root packagé is pydolphin you should begin with it. Otherwise use relative import

Comment: first of all execute `pip freeze` and check all the dependencies are installed or not. If your are importing something(like custom module), check those files are in same folder or not, if not in same folder, it should be in either system/user path folder or in extrapath folder (in .vscode>settings.json). Then try execute your code.

Comment: I am using this command in the root path fix it:  `python3 -m pytest test`

Comment: could you try to edit the json file (.vscode>settings.json) and add your path there like `{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./YOUR_PROJECT",
    ]
}`